# No longer getting the return value of a function after decoration

Tags: python, python-decorators

In the book *Python 101*, page 162, there is an example on a logging decorator function. The code is as follows:

```
import logging

def log(func):
   """
   Log what function is called
   """
   def wrap_log(*args, **kwargs):
      name = func.__name__
      logger = logging.getLogger(name)
      logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

      # add file handler
      fh = logging.FileHandler("%s.log" % name)
      fmt = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
      formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt)
      fh.setFormatter(formatter)
      logger.addHandler(fh)

      logger.info("Running function: %s" % name)
      result = func(*args, **kwargs)
      logger.info("Result: %s" % result)
      return func
   return wrap_log

@log
def double_function(a):
   """
   Double the input parameter
   """
   return a*2

if __name__=="__main__":
   value = double_function(2)
```

Normally, `value` at the end of the code should be equal to the return value of `double_function`, which is equal to 4 in this case. However, when checking it in the console after execution, I found out that it is equal to `double_function` itself, and not its return value (yes, `value` became the function).

Why did that happen? And how can I use `double_function` as a normal function that returns its proper return value?

Note: I am using Python 3.6.5.

Comment: Change `return func` to `return result`.

Comment: Ah, thank you, it was that simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@aran-fey is right

```
import logging

def log(func):
   """
   Log what function is called
   """
   def wrap_log(*args, **kwargs):
      name = func.__name__
      logger = logging.getLogger(name)
      logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

      # add file handler
      fh = logging.FileHandler("%s.log" % name)
      fmt = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
      formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt)
      fh.setFormatter(formatter)
      logger.addHandler(fh)

      logger.info("Running function: %s" % name)
      result = func(*args, **kwargs)
      logger.info("Result: %s" % result)
      return result  # Your error was you returned the function, not the result
   return wrap_log

@log
def double_function(a):
   """
   Double the input parameter
   """
   return a*2

if __name__=="__main__":
   value = double_function(2)
   print(value)
```